# Confusion about FreeBSD jail being up to date (or not)

Tags: freebsd, jails

I'm new to FreeBSD system administration and I'm a little confused about keeping jails up to date. Different commands seem to give conflicting information:

1. After `sudo pkg -j 18 upgrade`, re-running `sudo pkg -j 18 upgrade --dry-run` tells me `Your packages are up to date`. So far so good.
2. `sudo pkg -j 18 audit -F` however will tell me `15 problem(s) in 5 installed package(s) found`. Since we previously established that all packages are up to date, how can that be? Does that mean the listed vulnerabilities are known but not patched yet?
3. To make things even more confusing `sudo pkg -j 18 version -vRL= | grep 'needs updating'` tells me there are two packages that need updating.

What's the truth?